Some letters are cut in the checkbox lables
I run the typical example of DLGCreateDialog in GMS 3.2.xx and GMS 3.5.xx
TagGroup DLG, DLGItems
DLG = DLGCreateDialog( "Please enter strings", DLGItems )
TagGroup opt1tg = DLGCreateCheckBox( "Option 1", 0)
TagGroup opt2tg = DLGCreateCheckBox( "Option 2", 1)
TagGroup opt3tg = DLGCreateCheckBox( "Option 3", 1)
DLGitems.DLGAddElement( opt1tg )
DLGitems.DLGAddElement( opt2tg )
DLGitems.DLGAddElement( opt3tg )
if ( !Alloc( UIframe ).Init( DLG ).Pose() )
Throw( "User abort." )
Result( "Option 1: " + opt1tg.DLGGetValue() + "\n" )
Result( "Option 2: " + opt2tg.DLGGetValue() + "\n" )
Result( "Option 3: " + ( opt3tg.DLGGetValue() ? "enabled" : "disabled" ) + "\n" )

But the dialog only shows the first several letters of lable, such as "Optio...". This code can work perfectly in older GMS 2.3.xxx.

I cannot understand the reason and don't know resolution. :(

Running your script on my 3.5.3 installation (Windows7, English OS) gives me:

However, I do notice that you're font is different from mine. Can I assume this is not on an English OS? It looks like the Windows default font is different which throws the width-calculation off.
You can try to report this as an issue at Gatan's issue-tracker webpage, but I believe DigitalMicrograph specifies English-OS as a requirement. So it might not be seen as high-priority item.
As a "fix": Try using DLGInternalPadding() to extend the fields artificially.
I cannot try this - as I don't experience the problem - but it would work something like this:
TagGroup DLG, DLGItems
DLG = DLGCreateDialog( "Please enter strings", DLGItems )
TagGroup opt1tg = DLGCreateCheckBox( "Option 1", 0).DLGInternalPadding(20,0)
TagGroup opt2tg = DLGCreateCheckBox( "Option 2", 1).DLGInternalPadding(20,0)
TagGroup opt3tg = DLGCreateCheckBox( "Option 3", 1).DLGInternalPadding(20,0)
DLGitems.DLGAddElement( opt1tg )
DLGitems.DLGAddElement( opt2tg )
DLGitems.DLGAddElement( opt3tg )
if ( !Alloc( UIframe ).Init( DLG ).Pose() )
Throw( "User abort." )
Result( "Option 1: " + opt1tg.DLGGetValue() + "\n" )
Result( "Option 2: " + opt2tg.DLGGetValue() + "\n" )
Result( "Option 3: " + ( opt3tg.DLGGetValue() ? "enabled" : "disabled" ) + "\n" )


You are right! I use a Chinese Win 11. I modify the code following your suggestion and it works well. But the strange is GMS 2.3.xxx can perform correctly although in Chinese Win 11.  I will report to Gatan's team and hope they correct this bug. Thank you very much!!!

GMS 3.x (up to 3.5, haven't try 3.6) UI doesn't play well with Chinese (Traditional or Simplified) version of Windows. With above "solution" we can get around script-based UI but system UI will still suffer similar issue. Once we set the Windows default language to English then it will work fine.

@YuanYao GMS 2.x has a completely different UI backbone than GMS 3+. It is not surprising, that these two behave differently. Old UI's didn't even have to consider things like dynamic screen DPI changes and the like. (They thus look awful on 4K monitors with custom DPI settings)

Sure. I understand your comments on performance of GMS at the different version of Windows.
